# Matlab - Use Decimals in Symbolic Expression

Tags: matlab, decimal, symbolic-math

In this simple example, using the function `vpa` in a symbolic expression one can convert the outer fraction into decimal:

```
>> syms x
>> diff(2*x^(3.7))
(37*x^(27/10))/5

>> vpa(diff(2*x^(3.7)))
7.4*x^(27/10)
```

But the result still preserves a fraction in the exponent. 
How could force Matlab to use decimals whenever possible?

Answer (score 3):

Only for MATLAB 2019a and later:

```
>> sympref('FloatingPointOutput',true);
>> diff(2*x^(3.7))

ans =

7.4000*x^2.7000
```

And to return to the defaults:

```
>> sympref('FloatingPointOutput','default');
>> diff(2*x^(3.7))

ans =

(37*x^(27/10))/5
```

[documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/modify-output-of-symbolic-results.html)

Comment: I am sorry, but i am using Matlab R2018a... It seems this option is not implemented.

Comment: Yes the option is not mentioned in the 2018a documentation: https://mathworks.com/help/releases/R2018a/symbolic/sympref.html